# Google api moments error code 400 php

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

Im trying to post some activity to a users profile in their google+.

i have been searching all the post about moments problem but still i cant solve my problem. below are my codes

```
    $requestVisibleActions = array(
    'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity');
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("PHP Google OAuth Login Example");
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setDeveloperKey($simple_api_key);
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
    $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");    
    $client->setRequestVisibleActions($requestVisibleActions);

    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

    // Add Access Token to Session
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    // Set Access Token to make Request
    if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    // Post moment from mysite
    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $moment = new Google_Service_Plus_Moment();
    $moment->setType('http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity');
    $itemScope = new Google_Service_Plus_ItemScope();
    $itemScope->setUrl('http://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/examples/thing');
    $moment->setTarget($itemScope);
    $momentResult = $plus->moments->insert('me', 'vault',$moment);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {    
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    redirect($authUrl);
    }
```

but i get a google exception error

Type: Google_Service_Exception

```
Message: Error calling POST 
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/moments/vault?key=xxxxxxx: 
(400) Unable to fetch metadata.
Filename: /home2/mysite/public_html/application/libraries/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Http/REST.php
```

When i try to access the post url i get this.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

i realy dont know where im wrong. please help me

Comment: kindly help anyone please :( ive been searching for this the whole 8hrs of my shift

Answer (score 1):

[Moments: insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) Record a moment representing a user's action such as making a purchase or commenting on a blog. Writing moments involves specifying the type, which is a moment type, and posting that type of moment's required fields.

[Moments](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments#resource) describe activities that users engage within your app.

Momemt types is the same as [App Activity Types](https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types/) they are:

> AddAction
>   ,BuyAction,CheckInAction,CommentAction,CreateAction,DiscoverAction,ListenAction,ReserveAction,ReviewAction,WantAction

A moment is **NOT** posting to a users Google+ stream.  It is **NOT** possible to post some activity to a users profile in their Google+.

Comment: @DalmTo hi , i understand that moment is not posting in google+ stream. i just wanted to have an activity log from my site. but i cant get it working